# (#210) User not visible - cannot post to user's wall

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to post something to users' walls without their login. 
The error 210 User not visible always occur but I have got the extended permissions:
1.Manage_pages
2.Check-ins
3.offline_access
4.publish_stream
5.read_stream
privacy setting “Who can post on your Wall?” also set to “Everyone”. Can facebook do my want or are there any permission missing? The following is my php code for the test and the user_id set to my other facebook id.

```
<?php 
require_once 'phpsdk/src/facebook.php';
'appId'  => 'my_app_id',
  'secret' => 'my_app_secret',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$args = array(
    'message'   => 'Test',
    'link'      => 'http://dev.goinggreentoday.com/',
    'caption'   => 'Welcome to GGT'
);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/user_id/feed", "post", $args);
?>
```

Comment: there's soemthing wrong with your code (`$facebook = new Facebook(array(`  is missing). Also make sure that the app `access_token` is created successfully otherwise you won't be able to post

Comment: Thanks ifaour
$facebook = new Facebook(array (appId,secret)) have set before  
and the access_token also was created successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Apps can't post on their own behalf to users' Profiles. You need to use a user access token for this.

Comment: Are you sure about this? As far as I know, if the user already granted your app the `publish_stream` permission...no need for a user `access_token` to publish. an app `access_token` is enough (just tried it on graph api explorer).

Comment: Yes, you're correct I believe, I thought the OP was trying to post *as* the app, not as the user using the app secret :/

Answer (score 1):

Some users don't allow to post at their wall at all. This is propably why your app can't post to your users wall either.

Comment: is it psosible to test if user's wall is blocked or not?

Comment: Just try to create a wallpost. If the create is successful, you get an ID returned.